# How to hide offcanvas elements in Gravit Designer

Tags: canvas

I just started to teach myself some UI Design lessons, but since I dont want (and can't afford) a Mac, i had to look for a good alternative to Sketch, which runs on Windows. I stumbled upon [Gravit Designer](https://gravit.io/) in another question here, and it seems to do the job pretty well for me.

Now I have some Objects, which are part or completely off-canvas (as you can see in the image below), and I want to hide everything off-canvas. I know it is obiously not shown, when I export it, but I would like to hide it in the Designer as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution, so if anyone else finds this question in the future, this is how it works:

Go to `View -> Viewmode` and set it to `Output View`

[image]